# Vanilla Javascript - add amount of input to total value with different minimum values on inputs

Tags: javascript

I have three different inputs inside a  modal that represents three different "stock" items. if a user adds a value in the input related to that specific item with a minimum of the value stipulated I want to add that input value to the total amount. but I'm stuck with looping over the buttons and calling the addAmount function to get the correct input.

I might be overcomplicating things as I'm quite new to this.

any guidance would be appreciated

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.add-stock');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-stock-amount]');
let totalAmount = document.querySelector('.total-amount');

totalValue = 5000;


const addAmount = (e) => {

  inputs.forEach(input => {

    let setAmount = input.value;
    let inputData = input.dataset.stockAmount;

    if (inputData === "stock25") {
      totalValue = parseFloat(totalValue) + parseFloat(setAmount);
      totalAmount.innerHTML = totalValue;
    }

    if (inputData === "stock50") {
      totalValue = parseFloat(totalValue) + parseFloat(setAmount);
      totalAmount.innerHTML = totalValue;
    }

    if (inputData === "stock100") {
      totalValue = parseFloat(totalValue) + parseFloat(setAmount);
      totalAmount.innerHTML = totalValue;
    }

  });
}


btns.forEach(btn => {

  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    let btnData = e.target.dataset.addStock;

    if (btnData === inputData) {
      addAmount(e);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="total">$ <span class="total-amount">5000</span></div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" name="stock1" id="stock1" value="25" data-stock-amount="stock25">
    <label for="stock1">Stock1</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock25">Add Stock</button>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" name="stock2" id="stock2" value="50" data-stock-amount="stock50">
    <label for="stock2">Stock2</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock50">Add Stock</button>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" name="stock3" id="stock3" value="100" data-stock-amount="stock100">
    <label for="stock3">Stock3</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock100">Add Stock</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the user increments the value of any stock

Comment: I want to capture any value the user adds in but shouldn't be less than the current default "value"

Comment: @GavinWood, please consider accepting one of the answers if any has answered your question adequately.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is significantly longer and more complicated than it needs to be. Here's a way to get you started:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".add-stock");
const totalAmount = document.querySelector(".total-amount");

/* Increment the total amount by the given amount. */
const addAmount = amount => {
  // The '+' before the variable casts the value to a number.
  totalAmount.innerHTML = +totalAmount.innerHTML + +amount;
}


btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    /* Cache the stock amount of the clicked button. */
    let btnData = e.target.dataset.addStock;
    
    /* Use the above value to find the related input. */
    let input = document.querySelector("[data-stock-amount = '" + btnData + "']");
    
    /* Parse the stock amount to find the default value. */
    let defaultValue = +btnData.replace("stock", "");
    
    /* If the current value exceeds or equals the default, add it. */
    if (input.value >= defaultValue) addAmount(input.value);
    
    /* Otherwise, print a warning on the console. */
    else console.log(input.value + " is less than the default of " + defaultValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="total">$ <span class="total-amount">5000</span></div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="card"><input type="number" name="stock1" id="stock1" value="25" data-stock-amount="stock25"><label for="stock1">Stock1</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock25">Add Stock</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card"><input type="number" name="stock2" id="stock2" value="50" data-stock-amount="stock50"><label for="stock2">Stock2</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock50">Add Stock</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card"><input type="number" name="stock3" id="stock3" value="100" data-stock-amount="stock100"><label for="stock3">Stock3</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock100">Add Stock</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will go through it and revert back with questions if i don't understand what you did - if you don't mind

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You can ask anything you want. We all start from somewhere 

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code meets your requirements, please see the code comments for details. This approach requires only 1 event listener to be added to a single parent element of the buttons we want to listener to `click` events for - this technique is called **event delegation** and is a cleaner approach than adding many event listeners:

```js
const inputEls = document.querySelectorAll('[data-stock-amount]');
const totalAmountEl = document.querySelector('.total-amount');

// Get the initial values and store them as minimums
const minimumStockValues = Array.from(inputEls).reduce((map, stock) => {
  map.set(stock.name, stock.value);

  return map;
}, new Map());

// Add an event listener on the modal for button clicks
document.querySelector('.modal').addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    // Get the input that corresponds to the button that was clicked
    const inputEl = document.querySelector(`[data-stock-amount='${event.target.dataset.addStock}']`);

    // Compare the value in the input with the allowable minimum amount and take some action
    if (inputEl.value >= minimumStockValues.get(inputEl.name)) {
      totalAmountEl.innerHTML = parseInt(totalAmountEl.textContent) + parseInt(inputEl.value);
    } else {
      console.error(`Minimum amount allowed for ${inputEl.name} is $${minimumStockValues.get(inputEl.name)}`);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="total">$<span class="total-amount">5000</span></div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" name="stock1" id="stock1" value="25" data-stock-amount="stock25">
    <label for="stock1">Stock1</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock25">Add Stock</button>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" name="stock2" id="stock2" value="50" data-stock-amount="stock50">
    <label for="stock2">Stock2</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock50">Add Stock</button>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" name="stock3" id="stock3" value="100" data-stock-amount="stock100">
    <label for="stock3">Stock3</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock100">Add Stock</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating the logic. Just grab the `input value` and `default value` and get the max of it and add it to `totalAmount`.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".add-stock");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-stock-amount]");
let totalAmount = document.querySelector(".total-amount");

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const minValue = e.target.dataset.addStock.match(/[\d]+/g)[0];
    const inputValue = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("input").value;
    let totalAmountData = +totalAmount.textContent;
    totalAmount.textContent = totalAmountData + Math.max(minValue, inputValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="total">$ <span class="total-amount">5000</span></div>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" name="stock1" id="stock1" value="25" data-stock-amount="stock25">
    <label for="stock1">Stock1</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock25">Add Stock</button>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" name="stock2" id="stock2" value="50" data-stock-amount="stock50">
    <label for="stock2">Stock2</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock50">Add Stock</button>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <input type="number" name="stock3" id="stock3" value="100" data-stock-amount="stock100">
    <label for="stock3">Stock3</label>
    <button class="add-stock" data-add-stock="stock100">Add Stock</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, @SAM thank you for this, a bit complicated for me but I will definitely go through it and make sense of what you did, however, your logic is not working as expected. if I add a value less than the default value you still add the default instead of throwing an error or message to user. hope it makes sense

Comment: @GavinWood It is working as expected. If you add `-4` or less than `25` in first input then it will add `25` instead of `-4`

Comment: i understand that thank you, but it should not add the 25 from a UX point of view id rather show an error message if you get what i mean.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly as the value being added to the total is not the same value the user has entered in the input field. Also no validation on minimum amounts as OP said they needed in the question.